# Create android resource library with custom namespace like android.R?

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-library

I am working on an Android project(Using Android Studio, Gradle), and I split some logic and widgets into sub library projects.

I found that the `R.string.xxx` or other `R` references are merged, but I couldn't get my library's resource value if it has the same name as the app module. (I used `[libpacakgename].R.string.appname`, but the resource is still the app module's, not the library's.)

Is there a way of using a resource like an Android resource: `android.R.string.xxx`, or in xml like `myapp:string/xxx`, which "myapp" becomes my custom namespace or classname.

By the way, I also found that sometimes `attr id` can conflict, making compilation fail.

Comment: "Is there a way of using a resource like an Android resource: android.R.string.xxx, or in xml like myapp:string/xxx, which "myapp" becomes my custom namespace or classname" -- not that I am aware of. Libraries are an organizational tool, but *everything* in the library gets merged into the main app. The app needs to be able to override resources from a library, as the library's value may be inappropriate for the app's scenario. You can use prefixes and `public.xml` to help avoid accidental overrides, but that's about it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know this is an old comment, but I'd like to express my opinion anyway. Imagine having Java packages as an organizational tool, but then everything gets merged into one global package anyway. I find this very frustrating on Android. And if Android can preserve its namespace, there's no reason it shouldn't be able to do this for libraries as well, other than it being a deliberate design decision. At least that's the way I see it, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: What's worse, the documentation on crucial parts of this is nowhere to be found. For example, 'res-auto' in the 'app' namespace declaration probably stands for 'resolve automatically', and it resolves the package name specified in the manifest. (At least, I think it does.)

Comment: What's with the 'style' attribute being the only one having no namespace? Is it because it's just a simple replace mechanism that just inlines all the attributes specified in the style? And why does leaving out the namespace in the style mean to use the 'app' namespace, yet you need to specify the 'android' namespace for Android attributes? It's just a mess. Finding this question took me ages as well. No matter what I Googled, all I was getting is 'just type this, it works' kind of resources. Rant over.

Answer (score 1):

This might be possible by modifying internal gradle tasks, but this is no intended scenario.

An easy solution is to prefix library resource identifiers with e.g. the (package-)name.